# Grohe edge part

Tags: plumbing, faucet

I am trying to find the part in the picture. It’s part number is 01104213. The faucet is discontinued. [image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

I would think you might be able to find the cartridge/stem on the top of this piece, but the bottom is a "part of the faucet body" that is normally not considered a replaceable part.  It doesn't have moving pieces and shouldn't break or wear out.

If you truly need that piece, I'm afraid you need a new faucet altogether.